# QProgressbar shows also busy mode while percentage is showing?

Tags: qt, busyindicator, qprogressbar

QProgressBar works either as busy mode or percentage mode.

But i want to show the both!

In my application sometimes(not always) it takes too long time for just a 1 percent change.

So i want to show some kind of busy indicator effect while showing percentage.

how can i do this? do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can change your mouse cursor using :

```
QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
```

but don't forget to restore the old one, once you're done

```
QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
```

or you can add a second progressbar with more precision

Comment: Well.. i expected some Knowhow on Progressbar. But thank you. And...Mouse Cursor would be my last choice.